# C: get array of array-type struct members

Tags: arrays, c, qsort

consider the following struct

```
typedef struct{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char location[strlength];
    float timeInHours;
}appointment;
```

I want to use qsort to sort multiple appointments alphabetically. Because of that I try to get an array containing all locations of all my appointments and then give it to qsort. However, my code doesnt work, the console just freezes for a couple of seconds and then I get a random return code.

```
void sortLoc(appointment* x, int length, int size){

//length = number of appointments, size = carries sizeof(appointment)
    
    char* locs[strlength];
    *locs = malloc(length*sizeof(locs[strlength]));
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        strcpy((char*)(locs+i),x[i].location);  
    }

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("%s\n",&(locs[i])); //this acutally outputs the right locations, so the extraction kinda worked
    }

    qsort((void*) (&locs), length, sizeof(locs), (void*) strcmp);
    return;
}
```

the problem is the way I call qsort, because without calling it the method works fine. But I have no idea how to give my array to qsort in a way that it works.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is `strlength`? See [mcve].

Comment: Ups sry, I defined strlength in the preprozessor as a fix integer

Comment: Don't you really want to sort your array of appointments using the location os the sort key and not extract the locations and just sort them?  You can just sort an array of locations, but I am not sure that's what you really want to do...

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah All I want is to sort my appointments by locations alphabetically. I thought this kinda extraction is necessary, I have no Idea how to do it without.

Comment: Even if you wanted to sort an array of locations, you don't do anything with the array after it is sorted - you don't even free it.  So when your function finishes you leak that memory and don't know what order the array of locations was in.

Comment: You need to write a compare function that takes a pointer to two `appointment` structs and compares the `location` field. And then call qsort on the original appointment array. Something like: `qsort(x, length, sizeof(*x), appointment_compare);`

Comment: @kaylum Ok wow thank you, dat made it easy. I just used 
```int appoComp(void const * i, void const * j){ 
 return strcmp((*(appointment*)i).location, (*(appointment*)j).location); 
}```